# стиль произношения

Tags: стилистика

Какой это стиль произношения, подскажите пожалуйста? 
я думаю, что нейтральный, правильно ли?

В музыке существует большое разнообразие ладов. На слух легко отличить русские частушки от грузинских песен, восточную музыку от западной и т.д.. Такое различие мелодий, их настроений, обусловлено используемым ладом. Наиболее широко распространены мажорный и минорный лады. 
Мажорный лад
Лад, устойчивые звуки которого образуют мажорное трезвучие, называется мажорным. Сразу поясним сказанное. Трезвучие — это понимаем 3 звука, взятых либо одновременно, либо последовательно. Мажорное трезвучие образовывают звуки, интервалы между которыми составляют терции. Между нижним звуком и средним — большая терция (2 тона); между средним и верхним звуками — малая терция (1.5 тона). Пример мажорного трезвучия:
Мажорное трезвучие, в основании которого тоника, называется тоническим трезвучием.
Мажорный лад состоит из семи звуков, которые представляют собой определённую последовательность больших и малых секунд. Обозначим большую секунду «б.2», а малую «м.2». Тогда мажорный звукоряд можно представить следующим образом: б.2, б.2, м.2, б.2, б.2, б.2, м.2. Последовательность звуков с таким расположением ступеней называется натуральной мажорной гаммой, а лад — натуральным мажором. Гаммой называют упорядоченное расположение звуков лада по высоте (от тоники до тоники). Звуки, из которых состоит гамма, называются ступенями. Ступени гаммы обозначаются римскими цифрами. Не путайте со ступенями звукоряда — у них обозначений нет. Ниже на рисунке изображены пронумерованные ступени мажорного лада.

Answer (score 1):

Для определения стиля произношения мы должны *слышать,* как произносится текст... Может, рассказчикова манера - скороговорка с сильной редукцией гласных и проглатыванием окончаний (к примеру)? Такой стиль мы охарактеризуем как сниженный...

Но так как перед нами явная лекция, урок, можно предположить некие преподавательские интонации - всё проговаривается чётко и слегка замедленно для лучшего усвоения учащимися новой темы с новыми терминами. Это - высокий, или книжный, стиль.

Почему не нейтральный? Это не обычный рассказ, а ознакомление со свежим материалом на основе уже усвоенного (не объяснённые высота лада, тоника, терция).

Примеры [стилей произношения](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/russkiy-yazyk/119.htm).

---

Позволю себе предположить, что Вы неверно запомнили задание:

по тексту нужно определять не [произношение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), а [стиль речи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8), а это совсем другой коленкор...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это пять основных стилей, и, строго говоря, лекция - это образчик научного стиля, но в приведённом Вами тексте присутствуют вкрапления стиля художественного (например, когда оратор взывает к памяти слушателей с просьбой вспомнить различие между частушками и грузинскими песнями).